# What is the best way to check deep values in Immutable.js objects?

Tags: immutable.js

How can I check this *name* value in Immutable object?

```
var A = new Immutable.fromJS({
  b: {
   b2: {
    b21: {
     name: 'ok'
    }
  }
 }
})
```

I have only this solution, and this doesn't look good.:

```
if (A.has('b') && A.get('b').has('b2') && A.get('b').get('b2').has('b21')) {
  console.log(A.get('b').get('b2').get('b21').get('name'))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check with hasIn and getIn methods

```
if(A.hasIn(["b", "b2", "b21", "name"])) {
    console.log(A.getIn(["b", "b2", "b21", "name"]))
}
```